# What could be the antonym to the word "hyperonym"?

Tags: terminology, antonymy

Is the "hyponym" an antonym to the word "hyperonym"? In the sense of the terms themselves, this is true, but does the difference in terms apply to antonyms?

The subset that defines the hyponym and the superset defined by the hyperonym can be thought of as antonyms, but can one call the termins hyponym and hyperonym directly antonyms?

So, subset & superset - antonyms.
Hyponym & hyperonym - ?.

Comment: думаю их можно назвать антонимами, исходя из формального определения понятия "антоним" - ["слова одной части речи, имеющие прямо противоположные лексические значения"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Антонимы), так же как антонимами являются слова в паре "общее" - "частное"

Comment: Это вопрос про линвгистический термин, а не про русский язык. Я бы мигрировал его автоматически если бы он был на английском.

Comment: @shabunc пожалуйста переместите мой вопрос туда куда считаете нужным

Answer (score 5):

"Antonym" is a bit of a weird term, because it's hard to define precisely. For example, take "subset". Is its antonym necessarily "superset"? A mathematician might say its antonym is "not a subset", which is very different from "superset". So it comes down to what subjectively feels right.

Thus, in general English usage, I'd say "hyponym" and "hyperonym" are antonyms, just as "subset" and "superset" are.

Comment: _Antonym_ is multiply ambiguous because negation is multiply ambiguous; there are many different dimensions along which opposition can occur.

Comment: This answer may be improved upon with an explanation on the differences between gradable, complementary and relational antonyms.

Comment: Why not 'hypernym' -- 'hypero-' is not a prefix.

Comment: @amI From Doric Greek *ónyma*, "name". Same place the o comes from in synonym and antonym; in hyponym, the two o's meld together.